# How to Display a Report in a Specific format

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 9

Table1 Fields

```
Date ShiftName ID Name Intime Outtime Department

02-02-2009 MorningShift 001 Raja 07:00 03:00 Account 
02-02-2009 MorningShift 002 Ravi 07:00 03:00 IT
02-02-2009 EveningShift 001 Raja 18:00 22:00 Account
03-02-2009 MorningShift 003 Rakesh 07:00 03:00 HR
03-02-2009 EveningShift 002 Ravi 18:00 22:00 IT
03-02-2009 NightShift   004 Suresh 21:00 03:00 Admin
...,
```

From the above Table I want to Display in this Format

```
Date

ShiftName (Intime, Outtime)

ID's

Group By Department
```

Expected Output

```
02-02-2009 
MorningShift (07:00 - 03:00)
003 Raja
002 Ravi
EveningShift (18:00 - 22:00)
001 Raja

03-02-2009
MorningShift (07:00 - 03:00)
003 Rakesh
EveningShift (18:00 - 22:00)
002 Ravi
NightShift (21:00 - 03:00)
004 Suresh
...,
```

Group By Department

How to display the report in this format, I Know grouping, ordering, But i don't know how to display like this format.

Can any one give me a idea to display the report in the above format?

Need Crystal Report Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll start by saying that you have 165 questions and a total of 28 votes. Though it is not a requirement to vote it does give people a little more motivation to help you out. Now with that said, I think what you are wanting is something like this:

Since your expected output makes no mention of Department, but you say "Group By Department" I'll just make a guess that would be closest to your expected output. I'm assuming that you are wanting the employees by department per day so I'd assume that you want the grouping like this:

Group 1 - Date

Group 2 - Intime (This should always be the order) if you need the name then just put the field in this group

Group 3 - Department

Group 4 - ID's

This would give an output like this:

```
02-02-2009
   MorningShift (07:00 - 03:00)
     Account
        003 Raja
     IT
        002 Ravi
   EveningShift (18:00 - 22:00)
     Account
        001 Raja
03-02-2009
   MorningShift (07:00 - 03:00)
     HR
      003 Rakesh
   EveningShift (18:00 - 22:00)
     IT
      002 Ravi
   NightShift (21:00 - 03:00)
     Admin
      004 Suresh
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I want to display a date by page wise, For Example 10-12-2009, 11-12-2009 should display on next page. How to make it

Comment: @Gopal - You can check the "New Page After" box in the group footer of the Date section (Group 1 footer).